# Selecting records to print using Fastreport

Tags: sql, delphi, fastreport

I have a report where I would like to select which data to show/print.
I am using UniDAC as dataconnection and it works just fine when I don't select data, just print it all.
I have a varible in my report code called varDiaryGuid that I assign the value I want to filter my records by.
In my test this variable is assigned the value {A13CE6A0-7EB0-469A-87D7-3518FB9F365A} before opening the report.
When the report starts it shows a message box  Start report: {A13CE6A0-7EB0-469A-87D7-3518FB9F365A} so the variable is available as it should be.
But then I get an error saying Unexpected character - after some testing it looks like it is the { in start of the GUID.
Any one who has some ideas as what I might test next?

```
procedure frxReport1OnStartReport(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  ShowMessage('Start report: ' + varDiaryGuid);                                                          
  qryDiary.Close;                             
  qryDiary.SQL.Clear;
  qryDiary.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM qrymd_diary WHERE (flddiary_guid = ' + varDiaryGuid + ')';
  qryDiary.Open;                  
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use parameters for your queries (security and performance).

Define the query for `qrydiary` component with the OI as

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  qrymd_diary
WHERE
  flddiary_guid = :diary_guid
```

and in your code you simply assign the parameter value

```pascal
procedure frxReport1OnStartReport(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  ShowMessage('Start report: ' + varDiaryGuid);                                                          
  qryDiary.Close;                             
  qryDiary.ParamByName( 'diary_guid' ).Value := varDiaryGuid;
  qryDiary.Open;                  
end;
```

Depending on the sql components you are using, you also have to define the datatype for the parameter. Some of them can resolve the type and some need your help to do. Just check the parameter type with the OI.

You can read more about about using parameters in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Parameters_in_Queries)

Comment: Thank you for that input
I have been trying like that but with the difference that I used .AsSting like I have always done in other queries, but that doesn't work here in FastReport - but the .Value does

Sorry for not answering earlier, but I have been in hospital.

Comment: @OZ8HP No problem, you already mentioned the reason in another question here.

Answer (score 0):

```
qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE (someTextField = ' + 
                 varSomeText + 
                ')';
```

In this kind of queries where you send sql commands via code, you should quote the text/string variables like:

```
qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE (someTextField = ' + 
                QuotedStr(varSomeText) + 
                ')';
```

`QuotedStr()` encapsulates the parameter with "`'`"s

Comment: This is wrong for two reasons: 1) No, you should not quote the text/string  variable - you should use parameters, and then assign the value using the parameter's `AsString` property, and 2) because you don't quote GUIDs, so quotes or `QuotedStr` won't work here.

Comment: If your are going with "should" then he SHOULD use stored procedures. I wont argue about quotation.

Comment: No, there is absolutely no need for a stored procedure to simply SELECT a few rows, nor is there anything wrong with doing so. String concatenation is *never* the proper solution, though.

Comment: Anything wrong? What about database's statistical performance improvements? The operation will take big performance hit when sending plain sql sentence. Say, a plain query runs 5 secs., runs <1 sec. when used stored procedure; even when simply SELECTing a few rows. I'm neither questioning your experience nor your knowledge. But I say even "if you're selecting top 1 row, use stored procedure". So the database related jobs, insert/update/delete/select etc, would be in constraints of "the database" and can take advantage, any advantage of whatever db server being used.

Comment: I'm not debating over use of SELECT vs. stored procedures. The discussion here is about whether or not your answer is correct, and it is not for the reasons I described in my first comment. Quoting the GUID is not going to solve the poster's problem, and neither is contatenating the string. The solution here is using parameters, and therefore your answer is factually incorrect. This is also a simple select for what is most likely a single row (GUIDs are typically used because they're distinct values that don't repeat), so your "statistical performance improvements" are not relevant here.

Comment: It's some kind of hierarchical decision. Do not use quotation, use parameters. Dont use plain sql with parameters, use stored procedures. I see your reasoning, but don't share it. Because quoting GUID will solve the problem, and quotation works on GUIDs, it works on ADO w& SQL Server anyway. I'm ok with downvote(s), not ok with debating over database server ups&downs.